# Getting test project to import source using output path

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Typescript best practices are changing fast in 1.x and I'm no longer sure what is a good way to achieve what I want:

- My sources are located at `src/` and use `outDir` to output to `built/`.
- My tests are located at `test/` and I'm thinking of outputting those to either `built/` or `built/tests/`.

My test looks at `test/**/*.ts`, `src/**/*.ts`, `typings/**/*.d.ts`. To get it to import my soruces properly, I would have to do:

```
import { SomeClass } from "../src/sourcefile";
```

Of course, running the output file in nodejs would now fail, since in the output, `sourcefile.js` is located in the same (or parent) directory as my test.

Is there a good way to get separate TypeScript folders to think they're in the same directory as one another? Should I be using a `--declaration` as an intermediate step? And if so, where to put it.